# Double match in r

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, lapply

I have a huge data set in r with one row per individual. One of my columns shows a family identifier (note, `sex==1`, male, `sex==2`, female).

```
ind sex income  hw  family.id
1   1    10     6    fam.1
2   2    8      7    fam.1
3   2    15     8    fam.2
4   1    7      4    fam.3
5   2    9      5    fam.3
```

How can I do a "double matching" so I can match couples in the data set for many of the variables that I am interested? For example, let's say individual 2, female, married with individual 1, male, should receive an entry in a new column with his income (same goes for hw):

```
ind sex income  hw  family.id  income.male   hw.male
1   1    10     6    fam.1       10            6
2   2    8      7    fam.1       8             6
3   2    15     8    fam.2       -             -
4   1    7      4    fam.3       7             7  
5   2    9      5    fam.3       9             7
```

I've said "double matching" in the title because I don't need to match only the family.ID, but I need to find a male that matches this `fam.id`. The reason I am doing this is because later all males will be dropped from the data set and I will remain only with rows for females.

I am sorry I can't show any coding I've worked. I've tried many approaches using match, `ifelse`, `lapply` and even `unlist` but it is not worth to add it here as unfortunately I can't make it work.

Anyone has a clue? We can work with both `data.frames` or `data.tables` environments.

Comment: In desired results, why do records with sex==2 have data for `income.male` and `hw.male`?

Comment: Hi @Parfait6, because that is exactly what I am looking for: I want to add to the rows where sex==2 the results from sex==1 that match the same family.id. Is that clearer now?

Comment: You should use `dcast(DT, family.id ~ factor(sex, labels=c("male","female")), value.var=c("income","hw"))` I think, but won't post it since your desired output is something else. (DT must be a data.table here...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go with `data.table` package. Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(ind = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), sex =c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2), income = c(10, 8, 15, 7, 9), hw = c(6, 7, 8, 4, 5), family.id = c('fam.1', 'fam.1', 'fam.2', 'fam.3', 'fam.3'))
setkeyv(dt, 'family.id')

dt2 <- dt[dt[sex == 1, list(family.id, income, hw)]]
```

It will take `income` and `hw` of males (`dt[sex == 1, list(family.id, income, hw)]`) and match all individuals on `family.id`. As a result you obtain:

```
   ind sex income hw family.id i.income i.hw
1:   1   1     10  6     fam.1       10    6
2:   2   2      8  7     fam.1       10    6
3:   4   1      7  4     fam.3        7    4
4:   5   2      9  5     fam.3        7    4
```

columns with prefix `i.` containing values of males for every family. Note that if no male is present you will not receive any row. If you still need this you can do:

```
dt2 <- merge(dt, dt[sex == 1, list(family.id, income, hw)], by = 'family.id', suffixes = c('', '.i'), all = TRUE)
```

to receive

```
   family.id ind sex income hw income.i hw.i
1:     fam.1   1   1     10  6       10    6
2:     fam.1   2   2      8  7       10    6
3:     fam.2   3   2     15  8       NA   NA
4:     fam.3   4   1      7  4        7    4
5:     fam.3   5   2      9  5        7    4
```

Later when you need to drop male data you do:

```
dt2[sex == 2]
```

Comment: this is very nice, but I'd suggest to try two additional improvements: 1) use `on=` instead of setting key, 2) use `:=` to *update* `dt` directly instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for this amazing answer. I know my explanation was not the best one so thank you also for understanding me too!

Comment: It seems that in the case of my huge data set, the number of rows that are a result of the merge (I am using the second option provided by @danas.zuokas so I can keep rows that have no male present) is way higher than max(nrow(x), nrow(i)) if allow.cartesian is TRUE. I don't think it makes sense to have an increased number of rows. There must be a problem with my data set.

Comment: Labas rytas, @danas.zuokas. Any idea on why I have this explosion on the combinations? Also, I am not sure if we can ask here, but do you have any specific reading tips on data.table (on the top of the proper documentation of the package)?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that the dataframe is named 'dat'. You can merge the males and females by family.id with the merge function. You proposed answeer didn't make sense to me or to the otehr commenters but you can reassign "income" or "hw" within this new object.

```
> merge( dat[ dat$sex==1, ], dat[dat$sex==2,] , by="family.id")
  family.id ind.x sex.x income.x hw.x ind.y sex.y income.y hw.y
1     fam.1     1     1       10    6     2     2        8    7
2     fam.3     4     1        7    4     5     2        9    5
```

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817909/double-match-in-r/33823582#comment55412591_33823582):

```
require(data.table)
dt[dt[sex == 1L], c("i.m", "hw.m") := .(i.income, i.hw), on="family.id"][]
```

Extract the row indices where `sex == 'male'` for each `family.id` and add two columns *by reference* with the corresponding `income` and `hw` values.

---

where `dt` is:

```
dt = fread('ind sex income  hw  family.id
1   1    10     6    fam.1
2   2    8      7    fam.1
3   2    15     8    fam.2
4   1    7      4    fam.3
5   2    9      5    fam.3')
```